# Detect browser and not load HTML, cshtml cSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

is there an easy csharp (cshtml) solution for detecting if a browser is Chrome and then **not** loading a piece of html code. Alternatively I know I can probably just used javascript but it would be nice to use C# html combination.

```
    @Html.Partial("_Navbar")
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @RenderBody()

<!-- only load footer if browser is Chrome -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col l-foot">
                    &copy;@DateTime.Now.Year 
                </div>
                <div class="col r-foot">
                    <p>@Html.Raw($"Test - {layoutModel.Version}")</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: Beware that server-side browser detection depends on what that browser tells about itself and what server side knows about it. In short, it may fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure,

```
@if (Request.Browser.Browser == "Chrome")
{
    @Html.Raw("<<<<HTML HERE>>>>")
}
else
{
    @Html.Raw("<<<<ALTERNATE HTML HERE>>>>")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in the the controller, by returning a different view if browser is chrome:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    if (this.Request.Browser == "Chrome")
    {
        return View("ViewForChrome");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("OtherView");
    }
}
```